# Spark Streaming df.writeStream generate no output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using hdp **sandbox 2.6.4** and I have a spark configured on my local machine (host machine).

I have logged into the docker image using shell and have started a simple console consumer. And I am trying to consume that with Spark on my local machine (not docker container). it's not giving any error. however, it's not giving any output either.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("demo")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.readStream.
                      format("kafka").
                      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:6667").
                      option("subscribe", "test").
                      load()

    val query = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()

  }
```

if I log in to docker image and start another console producer I am able to consume all the messages.   I have checked the port and it's open from docker to host machine.

Comment: Why do you need the whole hdp VM just for Spark and Kafka?

Comment: I don't.. I already have hdp on my machine and want to write a program to store result back to hive.. This intelij code is for development

Comment: Why don't you use Kafka Connect HDFS connector or Apache Gobblin for that?

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe for the real use case, this is for learning spark streaming.

Comment: Spark Streaming is deprecated as of Spark 2.4. I assume you mean Structured Streaming? In any case, your code looks fine. If you see nothing, either the topic is empty, or there are silent network errors within the Spark UI executor logs you're not seeing

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a console producer where I am generating the message, so for sure I know it's not empty.

Comment: Where are you running it? From alongside Spark or within the VM/container? Try it from outside the container

Comment: @cricket_007 I would, however, my final goal was to run spark code inside the docker image/container.  for I am just doing testing. I will probably build a jar and submit it inside the container spark.

Comment: You'd be submitting to the YARN cluster, though. The only docker container would be the one holding the Spark submit script. The actual code would be running raw JVM inside YARN

Comment: That's besides the point. I'm telling you how to debug your network connections. If you want to run code inside the container, then fine. Does it really matter how data gets into Kafka then?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the advertised.listeners of the kafka brokers within the Docker container within the VM are not configured for external connections

Comment: Kakfa broker port 6667 is open from Docker to host machine.

Comment: I think you're not understanding the purpose of the advertised listeners variable. Port forwards are important, but not the only config that matters